# How would i write a regular expression to check for a string of text surrounded by equal signs?

Tags: php, regex

How would i use regular expressions to check for characters within the following string of text:

=== logo ===

I tried to use a regex tester but could come up with the correct expression for i've tried this:

```
 /^[=]{3}$/
```

1. I want search within a string find where the text starts with 3 equal signs.
2. Find a string or any other characters within the equal signs.
3. Find 3 more equal signs.. ending the expression.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
/===[^=]+===/
```

If you want to capture the text, surround it in parentheses:

```
/===([^=]+)===/
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jufXA/

---

If you might have equal signs in your text (but less than 3, obviously) you should instead match everything lazily (which is a tad slower):

```
/===(.+?)===/
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jufXA/1/

Answer (score 2):

How about as simple as...

```
/===(.+?)===/
```

For [**example**](http://ideone.com/pYyuIP):

```
$test = "here's ===something special===, like ===this=one===";
preg_match_all('/===(.+?)===/', $test, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Laziness is kinda virtue here: the regex engine won't advance past the first 'closing delimiter `===`'. Without `?`, however, you need to use negated character classes (but then again, what about `===something=like=this===`?).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
/([=]{3})\s*(.+?)\s*\1/.
```

This puts the text markup (three equal signs) in the beginning and then just uses a back reference for the end.  It also trims your text of spaces, which is what you probably want.

Comment: Character class is redundant here (`={3}` will do just fine), but your point is valid.

Comment: Actually, in real code I would not even hide the markup in a regex.  If it were Perl, I'd write: /$header_marker\s*(.+?)\s*$header_marker/.